# how to set up a DNS server in SUSE11 using command line

Tags: linux, networking, dns, bind

The results of a Google search on this topic are all "X solution". But the X interface are not allowed in the Suse Server I'm using, so I'm seeking for a "command line" solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use bind, to install and set bind to start automatically, do the following:

```
yast2 -i bind bind-chrootenv bind-devel bind-utils

chkconfig --add named
/etc/init.d/named start
```

You can then go to [this guide](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/bind/) to get details about configuring bind.